# How to count unique integers in unordered_set?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-set

A question that might appear trivial, but I am wondering if there's a way of obtaining the count of integers made unique after I transform an array containing repeated integers into an unordered_set. To be clear, I start with some array, turn into an unordered set, and suddenly, the unordered_set only contains unique integers, and I am simply after the repeat number of the integers in the unordered_set.
Is this possible at all? (something like unordered_set.count(index) ?)

Comment: Suppose I have the array `[2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`, and I turn it into an unordered set. Are you asking how to get the number of integers in the set (which is 2), or are you trying to get the number of times each integer appeared (so the number of times 2 appeared would be 3)? The first thing is easy, and the second thing isn't something you'd use an unordered_set for.

Comment: Well, aren't *all* values in a set "unique"? Isn't that one of the defining requirements of a set, that it will only contain one of each "key"? You might want to read e.g. [this `std::unordered_set` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Comment: Hi, it is the second thing,. Can I do the second thing using unordered_map at all?)

Comment: You can use an unordered_map so you can keep a count of how many times each number shows up!

Comment: Instead of an `unordered_set`, use an `unordered_map<key_type,std::size_t>`. For each key, increment the value. Voila!

Comment: Hi @daniel Frey Can you provide an example implementation at all say? Thanks

Comment: Once you create the unordered set, do you retain the original array? If you do, then you can count occurrences in the array, and the set is irrelevant; if you  don't then the information you're looking for has been lost.

Comment: @Lexka No offense, but I believe you'll learn more if you try it yourself. If you have some code and you are stuck on a specific problem, you can always ask a new question on SO.

Comment: Hi @Daniel frey, I am simply not sure how to read in the values of the array in the hash_map then get the count, I can't see that from the documentation. Guess that's why I am here asking.

Answer (score 0):

> A question that might appear trivial, but I am wondering if there's a way of obtaining the count of integers made unique after I transform an array containing repeated integers into an unordered_set.

If the container is contiguous, like an array, then I believe you can use `ptrdiff_t` to count them after doing some iterator math. I'm not sure about non-contiguous containers, though.

Since you start with an array:

1. Call [`unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) on the array
2. `unique` returns `iter.end()`
3. Calculate `ptrdiff_t count` using `iter.begin()` and `iter.end()`

Remember that the calculation in step 3 needs to be adjusted for the `sizeof` and element.

But to paraphrase Beta, some containers lend themselves to this, and other do not. If you have an unordered set (or a map or a tree), then the information will not be readily available.

Comment: But how would I do that say? Do you have an example implementation at all? Thanks

Comment: @Lexka - I added some more information for you. *"Do you have an example implementation at all?"* - I *hope* you are not trying to get me to implement this for you :)

Comment: Hi, actually, I am not working with the array but the unordered_set so I don't think your example is appropriate

Comment: @Lexka - you said you started with an array: *"... after I transform an array containing repeated integers..."*.

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer to the user2357112's question I will write a solution.
So, let's assume that instead of unordered_set we will use a vector and our vector has values like this:

```
{1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5};
```

So, we want to get numbers (in different vector I think) of how many times particular value appears in the vector, right? And in this specific case result would be: 1 appears 5 times, 3 appears one time, 4 appears 3 times and 5 appears 2 times.

To get this done, one possible solution can be like this:

1. Get **unique entries** from source vector and store them in different vector, so this vector will contain: 1, 3, 4, 5
2. Iterate through whole **unique vector** and count these elements from source vector.
3. Print result

The code from point 1, can be like this:

```
template <typename Type>
vector<Type> unique_entries (vector<Type> vec) { 
    for (auto iter = vec.begin (); iter != vec.end (); ++iter) { 
        auto f = find_if (iter+1, vec.end (), [&] (const Type& val) {
           return *iter == val; 
        });

        if (f != vec.end ()) { 
            vec.erase (remove (iter+1, vec.end (), *iter), vec.end ());
        }
    }
    return vec;
}
```

The code from point 2, can be like this:

```
template <typename Type>
struct Properties { 
    Type key;
    long int count;
};

template <typename Type>
vector<Properties<Type>> get_properties (const vector<Type>& vec) { 
    vector<Properties<Type>> ret {};
    auto unique_vec = unique_entries (vec);
    for (const auto& uv : unique_vec) { 
        auto c = count (vec.begin (), vec.end (), uv); // (X)
        ret.push_back ({uv, c});
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Of course we do not need Properties class to store key and count value, you can return just a vector of int (with count of elements), but as I said, it is one of the possible solutions. So, by using **unique_entries** we get a vector with unique entries ( :) ), then we can iterate through the whole vector vec (**get_properties**, using **std::count** marked as (X)), and push_back Properties object to the vector **ret**.

The code from point 3, can be like this:

```
template <typename Type>
void show (const vector<Properties<Type>>& vec) { 
    for (const auto& v : vec) { 
        cout << v.key << " " << v.count << endl;
    }
}

// usage below
vector<int> vec {1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5};
auto properties = get_properties (vec);
show (properties);
```

And the result looks like this:

```
1 5
3 1
4 3
5 2
```

What is worth to note, this example has been written using templates to provide flexibility of choosing type of elements in the vector. If you want to store values of long, long long, short, etc, instead of int type, all you have to do is to change definition of source vector, for example:

```
vector<unsigned long long> vec2 {1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 2, 2, 1, 6, 5};
show (get_properties (vec2));
```

will produce:

```
1 3
3 5
2 5
4 4
7 1
6 1
5 1
```

which is desired result.

One more note, you can do this with vector of string as well.

```
vector<string> vec_str {"Thomas", "Rick", "Martin", "Martin", "Carol", "Thomas", "Martin", "Josh", "Jacob", "Jacob", "Rick"};
show (get_properties (vec_str));
```

And result is:

```
Thomas 2
Rick 2
Martin 3
Carol 1
Josh 1
Jacob 2
```

Comment: Hello, this is a very nice and complex answer, but I am actually after something using unordered_map because folks earlier made clear it was useless using unordered_set. Do you know how to this using unordered_map at all without writing code from scratch? It should a three line operation at most surely, no?

Comment: I am sorry, but for now I don't have any other solution, especially one using unordered_map.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to get a list of unique values AND the number of their occurences. If that's the case, then `std::map`  provides the cleanest and simplest solution:

```
//Always prefer std::vector (or at least std::array) over raw arrays if you can
std::vector<int> myInts {2,2,7,8,3,7,2,3,46,7,2,1}; 

std::map<int, unsigned> uniqueValues;

//Get unique values and their count
for (int val : myInts)
    ++uniqueValues[val];

//Output:
for (const auto & val : uniqueValues)
    std::cout << val.first << " occurs " << val.second << " times." << std::endl;
```

In this case it doesn't have to be `std::unordered_set`.